# what is team project in visual studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, team-project

I am new to .Net framework and I am finding it difficult to understand all the terms and tools from VS2010. When you want to create new project there is an option for "Team Project".

I tried to find documentation on [MSDN Forum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms181477.aspx) and [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg983486.aspx) but the way that they explain it is way over my head.

Can anyone please explain to me in simpler terms

- What a Team Project is?
- and how and when to use it?

Comment: Not sure but i think it's a regular project with CVS support and team logic added into the project (things like code review, etc...) — please anyone correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Team Project is a feature of Team Foundation Server, the Microsoft offering in ALM (Application Lifecycle Management).  You don't have to worry about it if you don't use TFS.

TFS provides:

- Source Control (Version Control)
- Work Item Tracking (bugs, tasks, requirements)
- Automated build, test, deploy (and test)
- Management of QA Lab Environments
- Reporting on the above
- A collaboration environment

and much more.

Comment: So in short TFS works similar to Project management system is that right?

Comment: That depends on what you call a project management system. Give an example of one. It's maybe like Git + Jira + Hudson + a lot more, all integrated, customizable and extensible. And as of recently, there's a version that's free for 5 users with an MSDN subscription.

Comment: I've added some links to the [tag:tfs] wiki: [TFS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-team-foundation-server-express) and [Team Foundation Service](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/)

Answer (score 3):

You create a team project for Visual Studio Team Foundation Server (TFS) to provide a central point for developing a specific software technology or product. A team project provides a repository for source code and work items.

Please Read More:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms181477.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio can integrate with an MS Team Foundation Server for source control and ALM.
A Team foundation Server organizes its data into Project Collections, which contain Team Projects. a Team Project may contain many visual studio solutions.

at work we have one Project collection, and each Team project is a full system we've built, containing one or more solutions.

Keep in mind, TFS is a seperate product so you need a seperate license to run it, and its a bear to install and maintain.

There are a couple reasons to use TFS, but the most important is the ability to control access to code by multiple developers. it controls checkins, checkouts, merges, and history/version control. These features can be valuable to a single developer as well, but as the name implies the general point is to enable a team of developers to collaborate on a system.

Comment: -1: if you think it's a bear to install and maintain, you haven't done that lately. It's trivial to install it with all the defaults.

Comment: Yes we are on a 2010 platform, which is the one that pairs with VS2010 as the op requested. Perhaps TFS2012 is much easier, with more support options, but we are talking about VS2010/TFS2008.

Comment: My point exactly. TFS2010 is _much_ easier to manage than TFS2008.